TelegramBot invite_link always empty
I have problem to get the referral link which was used by new user to join the Telegram group. When I want to read
invite_link
``` from new member in group, it is always empty. I do not use any webhook and if it is possible I would not like to use them. I just want to read invite_link. 
I have tried this 


const bot = new TelegramBot(token, 
    { 
        polling: {

            params: {
                "allowed_updates": ["message", "edited_channel_post", "callback_query"],
              },

        }
    });

bot.on("chat_member", async (ctx) => {
console.log("Chat member status updated:", ctx);
});

but did not even get started when someone new enter the group.

I have tried 


const bot = new TelegramBot(token, 
    { 
        polling: {

            params: {
                "allowed_updates": ["message", "edited_channel_post", "callback_query"],
              },

        }
    });

bot.on("chat_member", async (ctx) => {
console.log("Chat member status updated:", ctx);
});


